# How to write a conditional redirect rule in htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have WordPress blog which is registered under a sub domain URL (something like http://news.main.co.uk). The blog's client decided to then adopt the following URL;
www.main.co.uk/news.

The owner of the domain set up a redirect so www.main.co.uk/news loads the blog hosted on http://news.main.co.uk.

The problem we now have is that traffic is coming via two different URLs. I would like to redirect users who arrive via the older URL (http://news.main.co.uk) to be redirected to the newer one http://www.main.co.uk so it appears that traffic is coming from one URL.

I am trying to write a rule to an existing htaccess file so that only IP addresses from the newer URL http://www.main.co.uk/news load the blog. How do I write a rule to that directs users from http://news.main.co.uk to http://www.main.co.uk/news, baring in mind that http://www.main.co.uk/news is using the old URL to load the blog?

Appreciate any help!

Here is the existing contents of the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Here is my attempt to implement the mentioned rules (results in a 500 error):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != xx.xxx.xx.xxx
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != xx.xx.xxx.xxx
RewriteRule .*http://www.main.co.uk/news/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is the blog installed in a `/news` subdirectory?

Comment: Nope, blog is hosted separately under a sub domain.

Comment: So it's on a completely different server?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Don't ask why. Long story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an IP redirect like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.45\.67\.89
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

BUT...It sounds like you're creating two problems here: 1) a redirect loop, and 2) attempting to rewrite a domain name that doesn't exist at the host.

If I'm reading this right, you want:

`http://news.main.co.uk` to rewrite as `http://www.main.co.uk/news` at a different host

while maintaining the current redirect of:

`http://www.main.co.uk/news` ----> `http://news.main.co.uk`

You can't rewrite the `news.` subdomain at another host to "appear" as `www.` because `www` is a subdomain itself and is likely already assigned to your primary host. You can unassign it, but you'd be creating a big mess for yourself.

If you're good with the `/news` subdirectory redirecting and resolving as `news.`, then you're golden (but that doesn't sound like what you want). The only way you'll be able to accomplish what you want is to move the blog to the same host and into a subdirectory.

On another point, your client's decision ***may*** be due to SEO concerns. A subdomain essentially functions like a different website, whereas a subdirectory functions under the same parent domain and is therefore considered "part" of the same website as the parent. So, all information in the subdirectory is collected and indexed by search engines as contributing to the same whole of the parent website.

Subdomains (such as `mobile.`) are often constructed and, therefore, treated as separate websites altogether, though Google constantly changes its mind about these things.

Just an FYI...